# I am struggling with getting the reward system I built for Roblox to work with the levelling bar I also built for the same game

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox, levels

I have been working on a Roblox game for about three weeks, and have created something that I am proud of, but I have one pretty significant error that I can't seem to work around. I want to make the game something that I can add to in the future, so I made a program to reward players with gold and exp points for killing NPC's. I also made a GUI bar to show the player their progress towards the next level. The problem I have is the gold will show up, but the xp will not. I have been banging my head against a brick wall as I have tried over seventy fixes, and the xp still will not show up on the bar and the player can't level.

My xp bar program looks like this:

```
--Player related variables--
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local level = player:WaitForChild("Level")
local current = level:WaitForChild("Current")
local max = level:WaitForChild("Max")

--UI related variables--
local gui = script.Parent
local exterior = gui:WaitForChild("Exterior")
local label = exterior:WaitForChild("Label")
local exp = exterior:WaitForChild("Exp")
local bar = exterior:WaitForChild("Bar")

--Change stats upon join--
label.Text = "Level "..level.Value
exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)

level.Changed:Connect(function(val, level)
    label.Text = "Level "..level.Value
    exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)
    wait(1)
end)

current.Changed:Connect(function(val)
    exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)
    wait(1)
end)
```

and my reward program looks like this:

```
        
local Humanoid = script.Parent.Humanoid
local Experience = 10
function Dead()
    local tag = Humanoid:FindFirstChild("creator")
    if tag ~= nil then
        if tag.Value ~= nil then
            local leaderstats = tag.Value:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
            if leaderstats ~= nil then
                leaderstats.Cash.Value = leaderstats.Cash.Value +50
                
                workspace.ServerScriptService.leaderstats.Current:Connect(function(Experience)
                    if leaderstats.Current.Value ~= nil then
                        leaderstats.Current.Value = leaderstats.Current.Value + Experience
                        else leaderstats.Current.Value = 10
                        end
                end)
                
                wait(0.1)
                script:Remove()
                
            end
        end
    end
end

Humanoid.Died:Connect(Dead)
```

I also have a leaderstats code that looks like this:

```
        
local DataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("butthole")



game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    
    
    local folder = Instance.new("Folder")
    folder.Name = "leaderstats"
    folder.Parent = player
    
    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue")
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    cash.Value = 900
    cash.Parent = folder
--start
local level = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    level.Name = "Level"
    level.Value = 1
    
    
local   exp = Instance.new("IntValue", level)
    exp.Name = "Current"
    exp.Value = 0
    
    
    
local    maxExp = Instance.new("IntValue", level)
    maxExp.Name = "Max"
    maxExp.Value = 100

exp.Changed:Connect(function(val)
    if exp.Value >= maxExp.Value then
        level.Value = level.Value + 1
        exp.Value = 0
        maxExp.Value = maxExp.Value * 2.5
        
        end
```

Something isn't talking to something else correctly, but I can't figure out where that might be. I'm not a pro developer, I'm just a guy trying to make a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom if you want to skip explanation

## Errors in Current Code:

The main problem is this snippet from your *reward program*:

```lua
workspace.ServerScriptService.leaderstats.Current:Connect(function(Experience)
    if leaderstats.Current.Value ~= nil then
        leaderstats.Current.Value = leaderstats.Current.Value + Experience
    else leaderstats.Current.Value = 10
    end
end)
```

### 1: ServerScriptService is not inside workspace

To access ServerScriptService, use `game.ServerScriptService`

### 2: "leaderstats.Current" **is not an [event](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/RBXScriptSignal#:%7E:text=RBXScriptSignal%3AConnect)**...

`leaderstats.Current` is not an event, so `event:Connect(func)` will not work. Something like [Current.Changed](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/IntValue/changed) would be considered an event

### 3: "Current" is not inside "leaderstats"

According to your *leaderstats code*, Current is not inside leaderstats, but rather inside level: `player.Level.Current`

Although  I pointed these things out, we won't be fixing 1 & 2 because *they are unneccessary*

### 4: Extra parameter "level" causes conflict

The last error occurs in the *xp bar script*:

```lua
level.Changed:Connect(function(val, level)
    label.Text = "Level "..level.Value
    exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)
end)
```

The problem is the first line of the snippet: **the 2nd parameter, "level", does not exist**.

The `Changed` event only has [1 parameter](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/IntValue/changed#:%7E:text=The%20new%20value%20after%20the%20change.) which is the new value after the change (in this context, is the new level). This means that `val` is the numerical value of your level.

**Simply removing "level" from the parameters would fix this part**

## Solution:

*Reward Script*:

```lua
local Humanoid = script.Parent.Humanoid
local Experience = 10

function Dead()
    local tag = Humanoid:FindFirstChild("creator")
    if tag ~= nil then
        local player = tag.Value -- making variable makes it easier to understand
        
        if player then
            local leaderstats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
            local level = player:FindFirstChild("Level") -- "Current" is inside Level
            
            if leaderstats and level then
                leaderstats.Cash.Value = leaderstats.Cash.Value +50
                level.Current.Value = level.Current.Value +Experience --Simply add the EXP
                script:Remove()
            end
        end
    end
end

Humanoid.Died:Connect(Dead)
```

*XP Bar Script*:

```lua
--Player related variables--
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local level = player:WaitForChild("Level")
local current = level:WaitForChild("Current")
local max = level:WaitForChild("Max")

--UI related variables--
local gui = script.Parent
local exterior = gui:WaitForChild("Exterior")
local label = exterior:WaitForChild("Label")
local exp = exterior:WaitForChild("Exp")
local bar = exterior:WaitForChild("Bar")

--Change stats upon join--
label.Text = "Level "..level.Value
exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)

level.Changed:Connect(function(val)
    label.Text = "Level "..level.Value
    exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)
end)

current.Changed:Connect(function(val)
    exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)
end)
```

## Additional Notes

### 1: Handling Extra XP

When a person gains enough XP to level up, the XP is set to 0 and the level goes up by 1. However, that means all the extra XP went nowhere. I've changed the functionality to account for excess XP.

*leaderstats script* (replace your current `exp.Changed` function):

```lua
exp.Changed:Connect(function(val)
    if exp.Value >= maxExp.Value then
        local newLevel = level.Value
        local newXP = exp.Value
        local newMax = maxExp.Value
        
        while newXP > newMax do
            newLevel = newLevel + 1
            newXP = newXP - newMax
            newMax = newMax * 2.5
        end
        
        maxExp.Value = newMax
        exp.Value = newXP
        level.Value = newLevel
    end
end)
```

### 2: Functions (Not Neccessary, but Recommended)

Creating *one function* to update the UI makes it easier for later changes

*XP Bar Script* (2nd half):

```lua
--Change stats upon join--
function updateUI()
    label.Text = "Level ".. level.Value
    exp.Text = current.Value.."/"..max.Value.." Exp"
    bar.Size = UDim2.new(current.Value/max.Value, 0, 1, 0)
end
updateUI()

level.Changed:Connect(updateUI)
current.Changed:Connect(updateUI)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I would have literally never figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

After taking the advice from kojocrash, the bar now finally works :)

Comment: Heyo, you should mark their answer as correct

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: There should be an outline of a check mark next to his answer. Click that.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok, yeah it turned green.